# ordering array of numbers returns invalid result

Tags: javascript

For some reason, sort doesnt sort correctly. Why is that?

```js
console.log(
  [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0].sort((a,b)=>a<b)
)
```

But the inverse works....

```js
console.log(
  [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0].sort((a,b)=>a>b)
)
```

Comment: The comparator function is wrong.  [Check the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: That's not how `sort` works, see the linked question's answers. You don't return a boolean, you return a *number*: negative, 0, or positive. More on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort So (if you want an ascending sort): `.sort((a,b) => a -b)`

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a.

The following function will sort the array ascending (if it doesn't contain Infinity and NaN):

```js
console.log(
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0].sort((a,b)=>a - b)
)
```

Comment: Is that the equivalent in C# of implementing `IComparable`?

Answer (score 0):

The function should return either `a-b` for `ascending` or `b-a` for `descending`

```js
console.log([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5].sort((a,b) => a - b)) 

console.log([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5].sort((a,b) => b - a))
```